# how do you write a file in java to desktop thats platform friendly?

Tags: java, windows, macos, io

I am having trouble writing to the desktop is this formatted correctly? The file won't even appear but no errors are thrown

```
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
File textFile = new File(home + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator + "Testing" + File.separator + "leadership.csv");
BufferedWriter out = null;

try{
    out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(textFile));

    for (LeaderProfile leader: leaders){
            out.write(leader.printCSVData() +"\n");
    }
    out.close();
}catch(IOException e){
}
```

Comment: Maybe errors are thrown, but since you ignore the exception, you can't see them?

Comment: Add `out.flush()` after you close the buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not print exception.

```
try{
  out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(textFile));

 for (LeaderProfile leader: leaders){
    out.write(leader.printCSVData() +"\n");
 }
 out.close();
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```